# Как можно подгрузить длл в определенный процесс c++

Tags: c++, dll

я недавно начал учить c++, +- 2-3 дня знаком с ним. 
И сейчас я пишу лаунчер, главной целью которого - подгрузить длл в определенный процесс когда юзер даст на это доступ.

Именно как выбрать саму длл через LoadLibrary я знаю, но как её загрузить именно в определенный процесс я не знаю, что мне нужно прочитать или как это сделать я не знаю. Не могли бы вы мне подсказать, что мне прочитать.

Пытался найти в интернете какой-то код и разобраться как он работает, но ничего не вышло.
Просьба если кто то будет давать код, объясните, что он делает комментариями.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/73324/

Comment: HolyBlackCat, прочитал полностью данную статью. И там есть некоторые моменты которые я не понял. И проблема в том, что исходный код который мог мне разъяснить данную ситуацию скачать не удалось т.к ссылка устарела.
Например я не особо понял тот момент, где мне именно нужно давать имя процесса и где именно выбирается сама dll которая будет подгружаться.